# Google Geo Charts Not loading through ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a **html page** through **ajax call** and the html page contains the following code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>   
function draw() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
                        ['Germany', 200],
                        ['United States', 300],
                        ['Brazil', 400],
                        ['Canada', 500],
                        ['France', 600],
                        ['RU', 700]
                        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
};

$(document).ready(function(){ 
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                                    google.load("visualization", "1",{"callback" : draw});  
                                      }, 1000); 
                    }); 

</script>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

The html

Every time I try to plot I am getting the following error:

> **TypeError: google.visualization.GeoChart is not a constructor**

Comment: You didn't load a package.

Comment: I didnt get u @AntoJurković. . Like how to make this code run ..

Answer (score -1):

Little late for reply but if useful, here is your modified working code,

Include this in your script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>



function draw() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
                        ['Germany', 200],
                        ['United States', 300],
                        ['Brazil', 400],
                        ['Canada', 500],
                        ['France', 600],
                        ['RU', 700]
                    ]);

                    var options = {};

                    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
                ;

                        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", "table"]});

                        google.setOnLoadCallback(draw);
```